How to go from a vector operator to its components?
(I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate, I couldn't find anything that answered my question.)
I'm doing an exercise where I'm supposed to get the matrix elements for the vector operator $D$ (the dipole operator) using the Wigner-Eckart theorem. I know I'm supposed to apply the theorem to each of its components, but I'm confused on how to use the conclusions made about the matrix elements of each component on the vector operator itself.
Trying to explain it "mathematically":
$$\langle \alpha^\prime,j^\prime,m^\prime| D_q |\alpha,j,m\rangle = \langle j,1;m,q|j,1;j',m'\rangle\langle\alpha',j'||\textbf{D}||\alpha,j\rangle
\\
D_q=\bf{D}\cdot\bf{e_q}.$$
So how to use the information from the theorem in
$$\langle \alpha^\prime,j^\prime,m^\prime| \textbf{D}|\alpha,j,m\rangle?$$

If you have the reduced matrix element $\langle \alpha’ j’\Vert \boldsymbol{D}\Vert \alpha,j\rangle$ — which doesn’t depend on any of the magnetic quantum numbers — you just multiply this RME by the Clebsch
$\langle j k; m,q\vert j’m’\rangle$ to get the full matrix element you’re looking for.
The point of Wigner-Eckart is to realize that the combination
$$
T^k_q\vert \alpha, j,m\rangle
$$
transform under angular momentum just like $\vert k,q\rangle\vert \alpha,j,m\rangle$.  You can verify this because
\begin{align}
J_0T^k_q\vert \alpha, j,m\rangle&= [J_0,T^k_q]\vert \alpha, j,m\rangle+T^k_q J_0\vert \alpha, j,m\rangle\\
=(q+m)T^k_q\vert \alpha, j,m\rangle
\end{align}
and likewise for the action of $J_\pm$.  Thus,
$\langle \alpha',j'm'\vert T^k_q\vert \alpha, j,m\rangle$ must be proportional, up to a factor to $\langle j'm'\vert k, j; q,m\rangle$.  The proportionality factor is precisely the reduced matrix element.
Thus, I don’t quite understand why your Clebsch has $j,k$ on the right hand side: you are coupling the component $q$ tensor transforming by angular momentum $k$ to a $\vert{j,m}\rangle$ state and taking the overlap of this with $\langle{j’,m’}\vert$ so that’s where your Clebsch comes from.
Note that in general the reduced matrix element will depend on $\alpha’$ and $\alpha$, which label specific states with angular momentum $j’,m’$ and $j,m$ respectively.  Thus, for instance, in the reduced matrix elements for hydrogen states, the extra quantum number $\alpha’$ and $\alpha’$ would be the principal quantum numbers $n’$ and $n$, respectively.  The reduced matrix element certainly depends on those.
Because the RME is agnostic to $m’, m$ and $q$, one usually selects values for this the RME is easy to evaluate.  Oftentimes this implies working out an integral over the initial and final states, along with the explicit expression of the operators, but on occasions (like in the case of harmonic oscillators for instance) then the RME can be obtained, up to some normalization factor, using algebraic methods only.

The k's were supposed to be the rank of the tensor. I've replaced them

@HectorFreire Your Clebsch does not make sense.  If you couple $\vert J_1M_1\rangle$ to $\vert J_2M_2\rangle$ to get $\vert JM\rangle$, the CG is
$\langle J_1 J_2;M_1M_2\vert JM\rangle$ not $\langle J_1 J_2;M_1M_2\vert J_1J;M_1,M\rangle$. Maybe that's part of your confusion.
